# Set multiple email ids while creating ActionGroup in Azure Alerts

Tags: azure, alert, azureportal, azure-webapps

I want to set multiple email ids in "Email Azure Resource Manager Role" while setting Monitoring Alerts through Azure Portal. I am not sure how to configure multiple user using above action. Could you please help.

Comment: you can always create a distribution group and target that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Email Azure Resource Manager Role`, there are just three options, `Owner, Contributor, Reader`. I am not sure what you mean `set multiple email ids in "Email Azure Resource Manager Role"`. If you select a role e.g. `Owner`, it will email all the members with the `Owner` role of the specific resource. In this scenario, if you want to add multiple emails, you need to add them as an `Owner` role in the `Access control (IAM)` in the portal(they need to be in the same tenant of your subscription), see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal).

If you want to just want to send emails to some other ones, you may need to create an email group and add the emails addresses which you need to the group. Then use the email group address in the `Email` option due to it could just accept one address.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Where do I create email group from?

Comment: @sudhirk I mean the group in the e.g. outlook with several email addresses in it.

Comment: @sudhirk This may be helpful:https://www.lifewire.com/distribution-list-outlook-1173665.